# Dialog-box changed on Qlikview

Tags: qlikview

I am newbie for qlikview,still developed some reports using guide-lines from it's manual.But,i changed some parameter ,where it changed the appearence of dialogbox of properties,when you right-click that chart.Any body know about this to go back to the previous dialog box? since it's too complex way to edit the entire properties at one shot.

Thanks & Regards,
Sushma K

Comment: Can you post an image of what you mean?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I completely understand your question, but perhaps you turned webview on or off, by pressing the below button?  That changes the look and feel of the property boxes.

[image: webView button]